# how to match tag with outer tag data

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to extract some data from html:

I have some html like this:

```
<div class="class"><b>Brand:</b> Apple &nbsp; &nbsp;<b>Model:</b> iPhone 5 &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
```

I need to extract something like this:

Brand => Apple
Model => iPhone

How I can achieve  do this?

this is my current code

```
preg_match_all("#<b>(.*?)<\/b>+(.*?)#im", $content['adoptions'], $matches);
```

Comment: See [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641) for a more concrete reference than the joke-answer-kept-for-historic-reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best idea to be parsing HTML with regex. Perhaps give a HTML parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ a go.